# Keep inserted rows in Temp table - after a rollback

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, rollback

I want to run some updates on a hard table within a transaction, and insert rows into a temp table based on the newly updated hard table, but I don't want to lose the temp table after the transaction is rolled back...is this possible?

I feel like there is an OBVIOUS answer here, and I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: If it's within a transaction, wouldn't it still rollback the inserts either way?

Comment: You can use a table variable, they don't participate in rollback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks Laurence!!

> You can use a table variable, they don't participate in rollback. --Laurence

This was my test to prove it:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (Test INT)
BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO @test SELECT 1
ROLLBACK
SELECT * FROM @test
```

Worked perfect. Thanks! Now to expand on this